# Tasks not being periodically picked from celery-beat by workers

Tags: python, celery, celerybeat

I am trying to test a simple Celery app.

```
config.py 
extract/
       celery.py
       celeryconfig.py
       tasks.py
playlists/
         playlist.json
```

**config.py**

```
from os import environ

# Configs
REDIS_HOST = "0.0.0.0"
REDIS_PORT = 6379
BROKER_URL = environ.get('REDIS_URL', "redis://{host}:{port}/0".format(
    host=REDIS_HOST, port=str(REDIS_PORT)))
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = BROKER_URL
```

**celery.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import    
from celery import Celery
from . import celeryconfig
   
app = Celery('extract')
app.config_from_object(celeryconfig)
app.autodiscover_tasks(['extract'], force=True)

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

**tasks.py**

Tasks are basically an `extracting queue`, like so:

```
@app.task(queue='extraction')
def playlist_generator_with_audio_features(username):

    playlist_ids = get_user_playlists(username)

    api = get_api_client()

    (...) # some more code

    export_playlist_with_audio_features.delay(username=username, playlist_id=playlist_id,
                                                  artist=artist, track=track, popularity=popularity,                            
                                                  energy=energy, liveness=liveness, tempo=tempo, 
                                                  speechiness=speechiness, acousticness=acousticness, 
                                                  instrumentalness=instrumentalness, time_signature=time_signature, 
                                                  danceability=danceability, key=key, duration_ms=duration_ms,
                                                  loudness=loudness, valence=valence, mode=mode, 
                                                  uri=uri, preview=preview)
   logger.info('Got audio features from {} track(s) in playlist id:{} by username {}'.format(
                                                                len(tracks_and_features),
                                                                playlist_id,
                                                                username
                                                            ))

    return True
```

and a `writer queue`, like so:

```
@app.task(queue='writer')
def export_playlist_with_audio_features(username, playlist_id, artist, track, popularity, 
                                        energy, liveness,tempo, speechiness, acousticness,
                                        instrumentalness, time_signature, danceability,
                                        key, duration_ms, loudness, valence, mode,
                                        uri, preview):

    path = 'playlists/playlist.json'

    obj = json.dumps({
        'username':username,
        'playlist_id': playlist_id,
        'artist': artist,
        'track': track,
        'popularity': popularity,
        'energy': energy,
        'liveness': liveness,
        'tempo': tempo,
        'speechiness': speechiness,
        'acousticness': acousticness,
        'instrumentalness': instrumentalness,
        'time_signature': time_signature,
        'danceability': danceability,
        'key': key,
        'duration_ms': duration_ms,
        'loudness': loudness,
        'valence': valence,
        'mode': mode,
        'uri': uri,
        'preview': preview
    })

    codecs.open(path, 'a', encoding='utf-8').write(obj + '\n')

    logger.debug('Exported track {} by {} with audio features. Playlist owner: {}'.format(
                                                                    track, artist, username))
 
    return True
```

**celeryconfig.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery.schedules import crontab
    
INSTALLED_APPS = ['app'] # include app
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = 30
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_IMPORTS = ('extract.tasks')

DEFAULT_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'

BROKER_URL = os.environ.get('EXTRACT_BROKER_URL', DEFAULT_URL)
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = os.environ.get('EXTRACT_RESULT_BACKEND',
                                       DEFAULT_URL)

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'playlist_generator_with_audio_features': {
        'task': 'extract.tasks.playlist_generator_with_audio_features',
        # Every minute
        'schedule': crontab(minute="*"),
        'args' : [(1),]
    },
    'export_playlist_with_audio_features': {
        'task': 'extract.tasks.export_playlist_with_audio_features',
        # Every minute
        'schedule': crontab(minute="*"),
        'kwargs' : {"username":"username", 
                   "playlist_id": "playlist_id", 
                   "artist": "artist",
                   "track": "track",
                   "popularity": "popularity",
                   "energy":"energy",
                   "liveness": "liveness",
                   "tempo": "tempo",
                   "speechiness": "speechiness",
                   "acousticness":"acousticness",
                   "instrumentalness":"instrumentalness",
                   "time_signature":"time_signature",
                   "danceability":"danceability",
                   "key": "key",
                   "duration_ms": "duration_ms",
                   "loudness": "loudness",
                   "valance": "valance",
                   "mode":"mode",
                   "uri":"uri",
                   "preview": "preview"},
        }
       }
```

Celery workers work on their own, that is, tasks dump `json` serialized data at `playlists/`, with the following commands:

`$celery worker -A extract -l info -Q extraction`

```
      [2018-12-16 23:31:58,075: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@Vitors-MacBook-Pro-2.local ready.
[2018-12-16 23:32:29,494: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: extract.tasks.playlist_generator_with_audio_features[0713b788-c004-4c0c-b1ee-85068287856a]
[2018-12-16 23:32:30,892: INFO/Worker-4] extract.tasks.get_user_playlists[None]: Playlist name: Discover Weekly, Number of songs: 30, Playlist ID: 37i9dQZEVXcRI2aS94C6hY 
[2018-12-16 23:32:30,893: INFO/Worker-4] extract.tasks.get_user_playlists[None]: Playlist name: Time, Number of songs: 10, Playlist ID: 1qxOGf3xD3fDQs03kwKteg 
[2018-12-16 23:32:30,893: INFO/Worker-4] extract.tasks.get_user_playlists[None]: Playlist name: Vocoder, Number of songs: 280, Playlist ID: 7nROSBznyIkVgjSdNaHDxm
```

and

`$ celery worker -A extract -l info -Q writer`

```
       [2018-12-16 23:32:14,198: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@Vitors-MacBook-Pro-2.local ready.
[2018-12-16 23:32:32,467: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: extract.tasks.export_playlist_with_audio_features[a73f776d-2412-4aed-8e84-50c6485ebac8]
[2018-12-16 23:32:32,470: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: extract.tasks.export_playlist_with_audio_features[930fb552-5687-48ce-b61d-b573a79aa13c]
[2018-12-16 23:32:32,479: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: extract.tasks.export_playlist_with_audio_features[162a77a1-20ba-48c3-86c3-bb9c51eeed75]
[2018-12-16 23:32:32,486: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: extract.tasks.export_playlist_with_audio_features[89eff015-e692-4af0-a7a8-dcad06dc2e3f]
```

### Problem

But when I try to use `celery beat` for the tasks, only the first round tasks are picked by workers, but not periodically.

`celery beat -A app.celery --schedule=/tmp/celerybeat-schedule --loglevel=INFO --pidfile=/tmp/celerybeat.pid`

```
Configuration ->
    . broker -> redis://localhost:6379/0
    . loader -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
    . scheduler -> celery.beat.PersistentScheduler
    . db -> /tmp/celerybeat-schedule
    . logfile -> [stderr]@%INFO
    . maxinterval -> now (0s)
[2018-12-16 23:32:32,706: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...
 [2018-12-16 23:32:32,736: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task export_playlist_with_audio_features (tasks.export_playlist_with_audio_features)
[2018-12-16 23:32:32,743: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task playlist_generator_with_audio_features (tasks.playlist_generator_with_audio_features)
[2018-12-16 23:33:00,000: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task playlist_generator_with_audio_features (tasks.playlist_generator_with_audio_features)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: did you try starting beat with -A extract instead of app.celery?

Comment: yes, it does not work: task is sent but not received by workers. starting with the command used in the question, the *first* task is *sent and received* by workers, but then the following periodic taks are *only sent but not received* by workers.

Comment: I'm wondering if you need to specify the queue name in the periodic task options. I have a hunch that the beat scheduler is using a different queue. Try running with log level of debug and see if that yields any more useful information.

Comment: It's a bad practice to name your moduleы as libraries names. In your case, it's celery.py. At least you will be unable to import celery from another module in that directory, and, also, that can break your app and raise errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@app.task(queue='extraction')
```

The options here will not be used by beat. Use the `@periodic_task` decorator to have beat and the regular celery client use a particular queue.

```
@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(minute='5'),
           queue='celery_periodic',
           options={'queue': 'celery_periodic'})
```

- `queue='celery_periodic'` option is used when you invoke task from code (.delay or .apply_async)
- `options={'queue': 'celery_periodic'}` option is used when celery beat invokes it.

You can also provide beat options in the schedule config like

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
   'playlist_generator_with_audio_features': {
        'task': 'extract.tasks.playlist_generator_with_audio_features',
        'schedule': crontab(minute="*"),
        'options': {'queue' : 'celery_periodic'} # specify queue
    },
}
```

Comment: actually, `@app.task(queue='extraction')` does work, if I provide the arg `name='playlist_generator_with_audio_features'`, but I accepted te answer because it offered a clean solution, thanks. has not `@periodic_task`been deprecated, though?